# Am I eliding correctly "haven't" etc? (AmE)

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I am trying to learn American accent and I am practicing using this sentence:

> Hey, I haven't seen you in a while.
>   Yeah, well, actually, today was the first day I worked out since a while.

What I tried to do is:

1. cancel the *h* and the *t* in **haven't*
2. *today* becomes *t'day*
3. *was the* becomes *was a*
4. *first day* becomes *firs day*
5. *worked out* becomes *work dout*

I uploaded my recording to these links:

http://www.filedropper.com/record0004

http://www.megafileupload.com/U1a/Record_0004.wav

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=63340961763448462845

Comment: May I suggest Soundcloud? I'm not sure I'd want to download something that may be insecure to answer your question!

Comment: @Iplodman here you go https://soundcloud.com/user456341202/record-0004

Comment: We'd say "...today was th'firstday I've workedout in a while".  "Since a while" is unidiomatic.

Comment: @TRomano thanks for your comment, please could you give me a summary of my mistakes?

Comment: Thanks! Just quickly, *Worked* sounds a bit like *walked* in that.

Comment: I didn't listen, but: #2,3,4,&5 are correct.  But for #1 you don't need to "cancel" any letter. Haven't is usually pronounced **haven't**. (And TRomano is correct about _in a while_.)

Comment: This isn't the summary you requested, Marco, but IMO the principal error you're making is that you're striving for *rapidity*. At this stage, you should not be worrying about speed but should be trying to get the intonation to sound natural. Concentrate on your *pauses*.

Comment: @TRomano so did you mean that in this stage i shouldn't focus on the correct pronunciation which includes the cancellation? and i have to concentrate on the intonation?

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: Correct. IMO, you should not concern yourself with cancellation. Focus instead on vowel quality and on the intonation patterns of phrases and clauses. Try emulating the speakers here: http://learningenglish.voanews.com/

Comment: @TRomano do you mean to listen to that website, like this audio http://learningenglish.voanews.com/content/president-obama-to-meet-cuban-president-in-panama-at-summit-of-the-americas/2711405.html and then try to speak like them? but a lot of lessons on the internet suggest that the news is not the american english, they say that i have to listen to real conversation, what do you think? please give me advices to improve my speaking. i don't know where should i start from. i have already token a iBT TOFL test and i got 92 (very good), but i am not able to speak very good,

Comment: @TRomano i don't know if i should focus on cancelation or intonation or real conversations or grammer or improve vocabularies .... help please

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli. Although it is not the conversational American English you will hear at the sandwich shop, the beauty parlor, the football game, and so forth, the English spoken on VOA is indeed American English. Try to emulate the phrasal intonation patterns and vowel qualities used there.  *You can always later decide to "specialize" in one of the many regional "American accents".*  Just as the Italian spoken in Torino is different from the Italian spoken in Napoli, the English spoken in Boston is different from that spoken in Charleston, South Carolina.

Comment: You need most work with vowel quality and phrase intonation.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for your highly appreciated comments, I will really depend on them and stop listening to *daily dictation* channel on youtube, I will start focus on *vowel* and *intonation*. do you suggest any material? even if paid no problem. i got sick of searching Google, i have visted almost all the pages about english :(

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: http://www.npr.org/podcasts/

Comment: @TRomano thank you very much. I will keep on that podcast. i appreciate it

Comment: @TRomano final question please. do you know how can we get the "transcript" of that podcast? it opens ituens just audio, no text is there in order to understand what they are saying

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: I'm not sure. I'll look into it. The *You Bet Your Garden* podcast is a call-in show where people all around the country phone in to ask questions about plants and shrubs. It will expose you to a wide variety of accents.  The show's host has a strong Philadelphia accent.

Comment: @TRomano thanks for looking for the transcript, and thanks for the second suggestion *you bet your garden*, i will keep listening to them, and if you get any new podcast *even if paid* , i really appreciate it. best regards

Comment: I am voting to close this question at this time since no answer was chosen as best answer and the links no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

To my ears, the pronunciation of "haven't" in this sentence is just about perfect, although the vowels in some of the other words sound a bit different from a standard American accent.